# cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

trying to append a `line` element in react using `d3`. I keeps on getting the error

> cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

```
updateD3() {

   this.xScale
       .domain([d3.min(mockData, d => d.date), d3.max(mockData, d => d.date)])
       .range([0, 485]);

   this.yScale
       .domain([d3.min(mockData, (d) => d.discharge), d3.max(mockData, (d) => d.discharge)])
       .range([0, 485]);

   this.line.x(d => this.xScale(d.date)).y(d => this.yScale(d.discharge))  

   d3.select(this.node).append("path").data(mockData).attr("d", this.line)
}


render() {
   return (
       <svg width="500" height="500" ref={(node) => (this.node = node)} />
   )

}
```